# How do I parallelize an IEnumerable of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a variable:

`var contexts` where after setting is an `IEnumerable`. One of the properties on this object is also an `IEnumerable` I have:

```
Parallel.ForEach(contexts.AsParallel(), (context) =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(context, (child) =>
    {

    });
});
```

but VS complains about the second `ForEach`.

Comment: "...but VS complains" - I'm sure it does not "complain" but gives you a very specific and explaining error message. Can you share it?

Comment: What is the complaint?

Comment: What is the nature of your work, IO or CPU ?

Comment: @TheGeneral your answer wasn't half bad - if there aren't enough items on the outer loop, or if the distribution of subitems in the second loop aren't nicely evenly distributed, then flattening out the work with a `.SelectMany` is a good way of evening things out.

Comment: @StuartLC yeah i bailed on the answer as there were too many unknowns and the `Parallel.ForEach(contexts.AsParallel()` scared me into X/Y territory, thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to apply way too much nested parallelism here.

```
Parallel.ForEach(   <-- #1
     contexts.AsParallel(), <-- #2
         (context) =>  {
        Parallel.ForEach( <- #3
```

Assuming this is CPU bound work, you really don't want to be doing this. This will potentially create too many Tasks which will need to be mapped onto threads, which will cause lots of counter-productive context switching.

Assuming a sufficient number of items at the outermost loop with equal volumes, then it is better to just keep the parallelism at the outer loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
  contexts, 
  context => { ...
```

(And if the number of items on the outer loop is insufficient to keep all cores busy, or if the item dispersion in the inner `IEnumerable` isn't even and will cause tasks to complete at unequal times, then consider using @TheGeneral's idea of using `contexts.SelectMany(c => c)`, i.e. of the form `outer.SelectMany(o => o.Inner)`, to flatten the nested collections into one larger one, before parallelising).

If you still find that concurrency is too high for CPU-bound work, you can match it to the number of actual cores on the target computer, e.g. if you have 8 cores available:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
  contexts, 
  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },  
  context => { ...
```

However, if this is to be used for IO bound work, then `Parallel.For*` / `.AsParallel` are the wrong tools - use an asynchronous parallelism tool such as `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: But note that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648866/613130) it is suggested against using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` for CPU bound tasks (and for non-CPU bound tasks I will say that it is useless to set it to the number of CPU, because they will wait for things outside the CPU, like the disk/the network)

Comment: You're right, it's usually a bad idea to get clever at the onset, unless you really have profiled things first.

Comment: The outerfor each is restricted to a Max 15 records, with the second restricted to a max 30 (for paging purposes). For each of the Child records returned I then need to perform a further action. All are independent, hence wanting to use parallel instead of a standard foreach

Comment: Then a single, outer `Parallel.For` is just fine :)